# Deploy 2 GKE clusters, 1st cluster is dedicated for Spinnaker and other cluster is for my application

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, spinnaker

I am having a hard time deploying Spinnaker to my GKE-Cluster-A with Palo Alto in front. I ran to some issues along the way. So I am planning to create another GKE-cluster-B for Spinnaker only. Is it possible to deploy my application to my GKE-Cluster-A while my Spinnaker Continous Delivery is running on GKE-Cluster-B?

Cause base on my understanding, I have to deploy Spinnaker where I will deploy my application.

Answer (score 1):

Spinnaker is able to work with more than one cluster. K8s cluster (GKE, EKS, on-demand) is a provider. You can configure Spinnaker to work with a lot of different providers. See https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/ for details.